# django nginx gunicorn media files are not showing

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

media files are not served while static files served with no problem.

here is the setting.py file if django project

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static"
]

MEIDA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media/'
```

nginx conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_ip;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/ubuntu/nginx-django/hoshnyetli_project/staticfiles/;
   }
    location /media {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/ubuntu/ninx-django/hoshnyetli_project/media/;
   }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/hoshniyetli.sock;
    }
}
```

and project dirs are in these order

-hoshnyetli_project
-...
-hoshniyetli
-staticfiles
-media
-...

I tried many solutions but couldn't serve media files
maybe I did some mistake in project urls.py (i think in deployment mode no need to add static to urlpatterns)

Comment: trailing slash in location vs alias does not match